# Samsung Tablet Application Housing

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I was wondering if anyone could provide me with some insight on this question someone asked me, I found it lacking detail so I was wondering if you could help me answer this question.

1. How does Samsung house applications on the tablet (applications from the google store only), or can i just manually dumb the application on the table (i.e. internal application).

If so, are there any draw backs on adding internal applications to the tablet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking with your second question. But I can tell you that application APK files are stored in "/data/app/" within the system. This folder is inaccessible to the user unless the device is rooted. On a rooted device you can technically bypass the package installer by pasting apks into that folder.

The apps that come pre installed are somettimes put in /system/app/ which makes it so that the user can't uninstall it.

Hope that gives you a more clear picture.